# in bash use parameter inside another parameter

Tags: bash

I have list of parameters that take from a property file looks like that:

```
db_instanceid=i-0c2b12ae02d454018
db_secgrp=sg-8c2efcf3
backend_instanceid=i-0199621ba358d1814
backend_secgrp=sg-5e508221
frontend_instanceid=i-0199621ba358d1814
frontend_secgrp=sg-e152809e
```

in bash, I want to use an array to perform actions using those parameters,
Something like that:

```
declare -a arr=("frontend" "backend" "db")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   inter=$i  
   echo "Get PublicIp for $inter server"
   echo "$inter security group - $inter_secgrp" ; 
done
```

But $inter_secgrp itself will be read as a parameter,
so I get an empty string (which make sense). How can I read this parameter 
the right way so I will get the value of all "secgrp"

needed output:

```
Get PublicIp for frontendserver
frontendserver security group - sg-e152809e

Get PublicIp for backend
backendsecurity group - sg-5e508221

Get PublicIp for db
dbsecurity group - sg-8c2efcf3
```

Comment: Looks like `eval` is a must this time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could do it with indirect expansion

```
. parameterfile
declare -a arr=("frontend" "backend" "db")
for inter in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "Get PublicIp for $inter server"
   inter_secgrp=${inter}_secgrp
   echo "$inter security group - ${!inter_secgrp}" ;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The temptation to use `eval` is particularly strong here.

```
. parameterfile
declare -a arr=("frontend" "backend" "db")
for inter in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "Get PublicIp for $inter server"
   eval inter_secgrp=\$${inter}_secgrp
   echo "$inter security group - $inter_secgrp" ;
done
```

And then `$inter_secgrp` is what you want.

To be simple, `eval` tells Bash to evaluate the line for an extra time before executing it. Here after the first evaluation, the `eval` line turns to (for example

```
eval inter_secgrp=$db_secgrp
```

And then things after `eval` is evaluated again, so `$db_secgrp` gets expanded, giving what you want.